# Deleting answer on Jhana without knowledge of the Dhamma

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, site-evaluation

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a copy of the post which was deleted.

---

Householder Frank, interested,

the underlying question might actually seek for the pattern of certain awarness-release and good to search more generally after "[depending co-release](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.023.than_en.html)":

> ...conviction has stress & suffering as its prerequisite, joy has conviction as its prerequisite, rapture has joy as its prerequisite, serenity has rapture as its prerequisite, pleasure has serenity as its prerequisite, concentration has pleasure as its prerequisite, knowledge & vision of things as they actually are present has concentration as its prerequisite, disenchantment has knowledge & vision of things as they actually are present as its prerequisite, dispassion has disenchantment as its prerequisite, release has dispassion as its prerequisite, knowledge of ending has release as its prerequisite.

...for understanding how the path works. Saddhā, btw., derives for Saddha, giving up, giving, sacrificing.

*(Note that this gift of Dhamma is not dedicated for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but as a means to make merits, increase faith, toward release from this wheel)*

Comment: Hi, what is meant by 'stacks' in '..not meant for trade, exchange, stacks...'? Is it about stacks aa racks of moneybills value 1000 for a stack?

Comment: @Buddhism A reference to "Stack Exchange" -- the venerable doesn't agree with what's posted here having a "CC BY-SA 4.0" license (instead of a "non-commercial" license).

Answer (score 0):

I [asked the OP](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/34275/mn-36-parallels-for-section-where-buddha-as-a-9-year-old-boy-has-first-jhana/34279#comment58012_34275) to comment on whether it's an answer. If it *is* an answer perhaps he could edit the question so that the answer fits it better.

Note [this policy](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254):

> The best answers deal directly and solely with the question(s) specifically asked in the first place. Take care when "reading into" a question and answering some "deeper" question (that perhaps you think the questioner should have asked).

You wrote:

> The reason for the question is obiviously to find clearancy whether one could reach Jhana

... which may be true but isn't obvious to me (and other users) from the question.

The OP's question asked,

> Does anyone have quote and references for the passages in question?

... with the "passages in questions" being MN 36 parallels from different schools, which wasn't what you posted.

See also [Moderating answers which don't answer the question?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1676/254) for example

> maybe having -2 score would be a point for deciding to delete? (since we seem to downvote so little?)

---

The OP posted a comment in reply, so I think that's settled, unambiguous.

I'm sympathetic to the fact that it's upsetting to delete your answer, after you make the effort to write it, and given that you think that the post might have helped someone.

Even so I think that, the fact this is a Question-and-Answer site is fundamental to what makes the site useful and used -- we shouldn't ignore it when a post isn't an answer -- and we (moderators) shouldn't ignore policies (like the [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254) policy) which are so clearly upvoted by the community.

The site is relatively liberal (permissive, tolerant, accepting) about questions -- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) -- slightly different policies for answers.

Of course there are and have been questions which you're able to answer and answer well, only perhaps not this one (which *is* asking for literary references).