# Who keeps deleting my answer?

Tags: support, specific-answer

[First answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36567/254)

> I saw Little Buddha. Who is going to become a pet again?

[Second answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36576/254)

> Did you watch Little Buddha? I did when I was young.

[Third answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36578/254)

> Maybe there’s a chance the directors will bear the same fate.
>
> This sutra sounds like an inside job if you know what I mean. :)

[Fourth answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36592/254):

> Again? Who keeps deleting my answer? Please take a screenshot folks.
>
> At some point of time, the movie Little Buddha   became a video tape. Is there a sutra for them?

---

Two of these were deleted by Andrei, two by me.

This site (sometimes reluctantly) allows "Zen-type" answers -- see  for example [Should this 'zen type' answer be deleted?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1561/254)

But I for one failed to understand this as an answer to the OP's question.

The OP asked,

> Why does the Buddha have such a dim view of actors? I can imagine all kinds of professions that would be less ethical than acting. Was acting a very different sort of profession in Indian 2500 years ago? Would the same kind of fate be shared with actors today? Are actors frowned upon in modern day Buddhist countries?

Is there a reason why you think that these *are* answers to the question therefore shouldn't be deleted?

Please also note that "answering a question with a question" isn't really the purpose of this site, though it's one of several conversational strategies in real life -- [Are the kinds of question, and what kinds of answers are good, considered on Buddhism.SE?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1920/254)

Also from [the Tour](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tour):

> This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.
>
> Just questions...
> ...and answers

And of course it is:

> ... for people practicing or interested in Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice.

Answers which recommend that people not practice Buddhism are likely to be deleted. And Ditto -- based on [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254) -- answers which disparage specific schools or traditions of Buddhism.

And [Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254)

> The best answers deal directly and solely with the question(s) specifically asked in the first place.