# Content appearing on other places for commercial purpose (possible other purposes as given by contributors)

Tags: discussion

My person is not sure in how fare you might like to investigate that matter, only telling that this, if for such purpose, might possible limit the possibility of Dhamma-share here in a good manner.

Be clear that, if something, in this case Dhamma, is given for such as cc by-sa 3.0, commercial, but even if not-commercial, it is an agreement to use it also for "bad" and bad purposes, per law.

Questions and answers found translated (possible machine) in German language (btw. relatively good and respectful, in regard of language, as side-info):

https://antwortenhier.me/q/angst-davor-alt-zu-werden-im-moment-zu-leben-60316689769

There is less info about owner, origin...

It's to assume that such is found in other languages to a well in other use, possible far of the purpose Dhamma is shared here by good follower.

May you do as thinking proper and possible good to inform others about certain circumstances.

*Edit of Topic after answer of Nyom Chris, to cause no misunderstanding, from " (possible other purposes)" to (possible other purposes as given by contributors)

*(Note that this account in relation with Buddha and Dhamma is not dedicated for trade, exchange, stacks, entertainment or individual interests but as a means/possibility to make merits on it toward release from this wheel)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

It [appears here](https://antwortenhier.me/) that that site "scraping" content -- 10,000s of topics -- from dozens of SE sites, and reposting it in German, in order to have "content" which they monetise by posting advertisements.

I agree it doesn't seem to comply with the CC-BY-SA license -- e.g. because it doesn't sufficiently "[attribute](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)" the authors and origin of the content.

I wrote and sent a support ticket to Stack Exchange -- [which is what SE asks us to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/139866) in this case.

I don't know what SE might do about it, and when -- but I suppose that you and I need do nothing further.

Comment: "concern" is only in relation regarding possible merits done toward the Tripple Gems and further goof possibility for such. What ever goes beyond that matter... not the "business" of the OPs purpose, Nyom Chris. There is certain responsibility, in regard of one self, not just a worldly, as surely in a very touched manner mentioned in good will by Upasaka follower [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/the-buddhism-site-and-moderators).

Comment: I read [that meta-post](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2336/254) but don't see what reply to it might be useful. It seems to be in reference to the topic, [Is “impermanence” a bad translation of “anicca”?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/33629/254), and the cause of the problem is said to be that "people here who think they know everything, are not open minded".

Comment: No, that's just to initial case. Upasaka worried that you may not see the responsibility and heaviness of possible using the tripple Gems for other purposes. Since many times Nyom and others think worldly responsibilities are higher. It's as he said, not a game at all but possibility to huge merits or demerits, in care or carelessness.

Comment: And surely, no reply, aside of gratitude toward his goodwill is needed, proper, there. The single cases... that has been done already, so looking toward present and future resolves for improvements.It's practice, after all, most liberating if always improving to perfection.

Comment: ...and Nyom has re-acted again in ways of putting the sites interests higher as the Dhamma, in writing a defence there, (as just seen) instead value the care for his own welfare dedicated... repeat-offender * schmunzel * When getting imput to help him to protect what he regards as his own, he starts with "thank you", if getting what really helps him, he defenses, does not like to take healing essence.

Comment: I don't understand why you write that I put the site's interests "higher than the Dhamma", nor why you say I don't "value the care for my own welfare", or why you say that [this post](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2336/254) is "what really helps me". Because I don't understand the criticism I can't act on it. I see that @follower has returned to posting answers on the main site, instead of merely posting comments there or "pointing at the moon" here on Meta.

Comment: metta - meta here.